# Play sound files one by one according to current number

Tags: javascript, php, html

I understand question similar to this have been asked before, but none of it answer my problem.

I am working on a queue system where customer get ticket from kiosk and wait counter to call their number, for example 1023. I have sound files of each number in .mp3 format. BTW, the project is developed using php.

The two requirements are the sound files must be play according to the number for example if current number is 1023, it need to play 1.mp3, then 0.mp3, etc.

Another problem is these files need to be played one after the previous ends. I managed to do the 1st part but the sounds play together. Please help me, below are some of my code for the 1st part.

soundmanager.inc

```
public function getSound($in_value)
{
    $value = $in_value;

    switch ($value){
    case "0":
        $path = "sounds/0.mp3";
        echo "<audio autoplay>";
        echo "<source src=".$path." >";
        echo "</audio>";
        break;
    case "1":
        $path = "sounds/1.mp3";
        echo "<audio autoplay>";
        echo "<source src=".$path." >";
        echo "</audio>";
        break;
    case "2":
        $path = "sounds/2.mp3";
        echo "<audio autoplay>";
        echo "<source src=".$path." >";
        echo "</audio>";
        break;
//and some more
```

getSound.php

```
$word = isset($_POST['no']) ? $_POST['no'] : '';
$array = str_split($word);
$one = $array[0];
$two = $array[1];
$three = $array[2];
$four = $array[3];

$um = SoundManager::getInstance();

$um->getSound($one);
$um->getSound($two);
$um->getSound($three);
$um->getSound($four);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```js
var audioFiles = ["http://www.magnac.com/sounds/onlyroadlarge.mp3", "http://www.magnac.com/sounds/paradiserowlarge.mp3", "http://www.magnac.com/sounds/lordslarge.mp3"];
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
var audioIdx = 0;
audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
  audioIdx++;
  if (audioIdx >= audioFiles.length) audioIdx = 0;
  this.src = audioFiles[audioIdx];
  this.play();
});
audio.src = audioFiles[audioIdx];
audio.play();
```

Comment: this is a way of create a playlist right? But if so how can I make it recognize the current number? if current is 1234, i need to play 1.mp3, 2.mp3, 3.mp3, and 4.mp3, and then next number 1235...etc...while I have zero to nine mp3 files in the playlist. Ijust cant get through the logic

Comment: Just change the initial value of audioIdx.
Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/y3cmn5s5/

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function() {
  var audio;
  switch (dispatch_units[i]) {
    case 'ST39':
      audio = new Audio('sounds/alert1.mp3');
      break;
    case 'ALS':
      audio = new Audio('sounds/monty_engine.mp3');
      break;
    case 'ST38':
      audio = new Audio('sounds/twotone.mp3');
      break;
  }
  audio.play();
  i++;
  if(i<=total_units) {
      clearInterval(loop);
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: hi, this looks nice, but can you show me how to apply this...I am weak on javascript. Thank you very much.